# Retina compatible Word Processor?

Tags: ms-office, macbook-pro, compatibility

Microsoft Office for Mac does not have Retina support, which is a pain to look at while working on documents.
Is there a similar application that delivers the same efficiency and experience as Microsoft Word that has Retina support ?

Comment: TextEdit may not be a full word processor but I assume it supports retina displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update [14.2.4](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2742588) from MS now includes Retina support for Office 2011. In case the Office apps dont launch in 'retina mode' after applying the update, follow the instructions in this KB [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2761073)

Comment: Thanks for the notification !! Downloaded and its Retina :D

Answer (score 2):

Just use Pages from Apple instead.

It can also work with .doc(x) files and does even have a better experience. Your can get it through the Mac AppStore. There is also an Excel replacement called Numbers and a Powerpoint replacement called Keynote, all toghether called [iWork](http://www.apple.com/iwork).

By the way: Microsoft Office for Mac won't become retina ready. At least not the current version.

Comment: Any sources on that?

Comment: You mean reagarding the missing retina update for Microsoft Office? I read it about two weaks ago on a german IT news website. I'm sure you will find english sources as well when you google it.

Comment: Typically, major software packages (like Office, Creative Suite, etc) only support new OS features at the next major version.

Comment: Microsoft Office has been updated to support Retina display with the latest patch. For more info, see http://blog.officeformac.com/retina-display-support-is-here-for-office-for-mac-2011/

Answer (score 1):

You can actually make Microsoft Word retina with this simple hack. It also works to make at least the text in most other apps retina.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRu1J.jpg

Comment: Is this legit ?

Comment: yep! give it a try!

Comment: Yep tried and it does work .. however not everything becomes retina sadly...and you have to repeat the same steps every time you run office =

Comment: the icons do not become retina because they are not generated by the OS like the text. You don't have to repeat the entire process, you just have to minimize and then maximize it.

Comment: Yep seems like this would do until they release a proper retina version